Moving back to UK after gaining Citizenship in Spain through Residency
I am soon to receive my Spanish Citizenship by residency and want to know what will happen if I want to move back to the UK after the 3 year mark. I understand I will have to denounce my citizenship to the Spanish Government and pledge myself to the Constitution of Spain and not to use my original nationality again.
I understand I am still a British Citizen. The issue arrives that if I want to move abroad with my Spanish citizenship, I need to register as Spanish Citizen living abroad. If I use my British Passport, I cannot do this.
Am I able to apply for a certificate of Entitlement for my Spanish Passport to return to the UK? Would this be classed to Spain as citizenship or a Visa?
I just do not want to loose my Spanish citizenship.

This question is similar to: Naturalised to Spain and wanting to return to UK (home-country) without losing Spanish Citizenship. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
